# Erro no header ao enviar email com PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando enviar um email via PHP:

```
$headers = "From: contato@meusite.com.br" . "\r\n";
$mgm = "código" . $_GET['codigo'];

$enviaremail = mail($_GET['email'], 'Cadastro BUSCAFREE', $mgm, $headers);
if($enviaremail){
  echo "ok";
} else {
  echo "ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
}
```

Não recebo nada de formulários. Se eu retirar o `headers` funciona de boa. O que tem de errado nele?

Quando incluo o header, o código não dá erro, retorna 'ok', mas o email não chega.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muitos e-mails costumam cair no SPAM ou nem chegam mesmo para o destinatário devido a filtros nos servidores, entenda uma coisa, quando você usa a função `mail()` ou o programa `sendmail` geralmente que faz o envio é o servidor e não um usuário autenticado via SMTP, portanto servidores de email por segurança contra spams vão bloquear coisas como emails não autenticados.

Não é colocar meia duzia de headers que vai resolver, como:

```
$headers  = "From: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n";
$headers .= "Cc: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Sender: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: mail@testsite.com\n";
```

E se esta recebendo sem os headers é porque provavelmente a mensagem chega no formato PLAIN (texto) ao invés de HTML, e o servidor que recebe a mensagem permite isto porque mensagens PLAIN não tem muita interação o que as torna mais seguras que HTML, provavelmente.

Isso já foi muito discutido aqui no site, é algo que é muito falando SPAM, e a solução pratica e mais garantida em PHP sem sombra de duvidas é usar SMTP autenticado, existem projetos que já resolvem isto pra você, como:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer (download: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases - escolha a versão adequada a sua versão do PHP, faça isto com atenção).

Note que e-mails autenticados tem limite de envios por hora ou dia, geralmente um limite de 100 mensagens por dia, isso justamente para evitar que as pessoas usem emails para fazer ataques de SPAM.

### Como instalar o PHPMailer

Se estiver usando composer execute o comando na pasta do projeto:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

E no começo do seu arquivo adicione isto:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Se não baixe de https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases a versão compatível com o seu PHP e adicione isto no cabeçalho do arquivo:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

E então logo abaixo faça algo como isto, claro que as configurações devem seguir o mesmo que faria em um cliente de email como Outlook ou Thunderbird:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Basicamente é isto, uso o PHPMailer desde sempre.

Answer (score 2):

Fala, Ítalo! Beleza?

Cara, no StackOverflow tem bastante dúvidas relacionadas a isso.

Dá uma olhada no link a seguir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header

Aparentemente esta é tua resposta.

```
$headers  = "From: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n";
$headers .= "Cc: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Sender: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; // Urgent message!
$headers .= "Return-Path: mail@testsite.com\n"; // Return path for errors
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
```

Se isso ainda não resolver, edita a pergunta colocando o erro que é retornado quando você inclui o header, ok?

Valeu, espero ter ajudado.   :)

Comment: opa, é preciso incluir esse header todo ou só o que eu quiser? incluí apenas a primeira linha (From) que é o que eu estou querendo, mesmo assim, não funcionou. Usei o mesmo código da pergunta (apenas troquei a linha do header pela primeira linha do codigo que voce postou). ele não dá erro, printa 'ok' na tela, mas o email nao chega

Comment: tentei enviar o email com o cabeçalho completo exatamente igual ao que voce postou. retorna ok, mas não vai

Comment: Cara, se o e-mail não chega é muito provável que o motivo seja um bloqueio de spam no servidor. Pra evitar essa dor de cabeça, segue a dica do Guilherme Nascimento e usa o PHPMailer, sem dúvida é a melhor opção. Outra opção bastante interessante seria usar o Sendgrid. https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-php